# Generating graphics at runtime with Cocos2D - How to display?

Tags: iphone, graphics, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to create dynamic graphics for my game, which I'm building with Cocos2D. The graphics generation will occur at predictable, finite points, such as level loading. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to actually draw this at runtime. From what I can tell, the easiest way would be to draw into a PNG file at runtime and then load an AtlasSprite based on the PNG file, but I can't seem to figure out if this is indeed the best way or how to go about doing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I'm starting to get there. I've cobbled together a method that compiles based on your answer, now I just have to figure how why nothing is drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how Cocos2D loads Sprites or Atlases so this is a more general answer.

It might be worth taking a look at the Texture2D class that comes with the old CrashLanding example app. It uses a bitmap graphics context to generate a texture of a string for drawing with OpenGL. The code uses the CGBitmapContextCreate function to create a context. You can draw whatever you want onto it.

Then once you've finished drawing, you can either save the file as a PNG or you can call glTexImage2D on the data to use it with OpenGL.

There's more information about it in the [Graphics and Drawing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/GraphicsandDrawing/GraphicsandDrawing.html)
 documentation, specifically the section: *Creating and Drawing Images*.

Edit: It looks like Cocos2D comes with Texture2D so you should be in good shape. [Check out the initWithString method here](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/source/browse/trunk/cocos2d/OpenGLSupport/Texture2D.m?spec=svn242&r=242).